# Flutter: HTTP Get The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter

My http get function cannot receive response from my laravel backend. It just keep stating the getter 'length' was called on null. When I tested the api `http://localhost/ioio/public/api/settings` on my browser or postman it is able to receive data and response, so I am not sure why in flutter I would not be able to receive the response.

This is my repository function. I tried to print out to see where the code faced an error. It was stopped at the `final response =...` line and then it will lead to error at the catch function. I also tried using `await http.get('http://localhost/ioio/public/api/settings');` but the result is the same.

```
Future<Setting> initSettings() async {
  Setting _setting;
  final String url = '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}settings';
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'});
    if (response?.statusCode == 200 && response.headers.containsValue('application/json')) {
      if (json.decode(response.body)['data'] != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await prefs.setString('settings', json.encode(json.decode(response.body)['data']));
        _setting = Setting.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body)['data']);
        if (prefs.containsKey('language')) {
          _setting.mobileLanguage.value = Locale(prefs.get('language'), '');
        }
        _setting.brightness.value = prefs.getBool('isDark') ?? false ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light;
        setting.value = _setting;
        // ignore: invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member, invalid_use_of_protected_member
        setting.notifyListeners();
      }
    } else {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: response.body).toString());
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: url).toString());
    return Setting.fromJSON({});
  }
  return setting.value;
}
```

This is the messages where the catch error printed out.

```
Error in (initSettings (package:ioio/src/repository/settings_repository.dart:52:34)) | [http://localhost/ioio/public/api/settings] 
I/flutter (10877): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (10877): Receiver: null
I/flutter (10877): Tried calling: length
```

This is where my main class is calling the initSettings function during initialization.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    settingRepo.initSettings(); //this line
    settingRepo.getCurrentLocation();
    userRepo.getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the line number 52

```
print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: url).toString());
```

This is the line where exception occur

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'});
```

Comment: Can you add `settings_repository.dart:52:34` (52 line from file) to the question?

Comment: @fartem I have added the line number 52

Comment: Can you get line in `initSettings` method where occurs the exception?

Comment: @fartem I have added the line where occur the exception